# Groupby and reshape long to wide formatted dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bigdata

I have the following DataFrame. Describe the cities where each user lived

```
       City     Name
0   Seattle    Alice
1   Seattle      Bob
2  Portland  Mallory
3   Seattle  Mallory
4   Memphis      Bob
5  Portland  Mallory
```

Can you with pandas achieve the following?

```
     Name     City1    City2   City3
0   Alice     Seattle  NaN     Nan
1   Bob       Seattle  Memphis Nan
2   Mallory   Portland Seattle Portland
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here'e one way

```
In [619]: df.groupby('Name')['City'].apply(list).apply(pd.Series)
Out[619]:
                0        1         2
Name
Alice     Seattle      NaN       NaN
Bob       Seattle  Memphis       NaN
Mallory  Portland  Seattle  Portland
```

For Column names, use `rename` and `format`

```
In [628]: (df.groupby('Name')['City'].apply(list).apply(pd.Series)
             .rename(columns=lambda x: 'City{}'.format(x+1)))
Out[628]:
            City1    City2     City3
Name
Alice     Seattle      NaN       NaN
Bob       Seattle  Memphis       NaN
Mallory  Portland  Seattle  Portland
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do this in the following manner:

1. Retrieve the cumulative counts grouped on *Name*. To get the headers formatted as desired, add 1 to the resulting values obtained as it starts assigning groups from 0 and not 1 onwards. Use `map` to format the strings by adding `"City"` char at the beginning of these.
2. Set *Name* along with the above obtained result as the index axis and `unstack` the `DF`. Additionally, the `None` values could be replace by `NaN` using the `fill_value` parameter.

---

```
cc = df.groupby('Name')['City'].cumcount().add(1).map('City{}'.format)
df.set_index(['Name', cc])['City'].unstack(fill_value=np.nan).reset_index()
```

[image]